# ¿What does the buyer of an NFT get?

Tags: nft

There are two relationships in NFTs, one is the underlying relationship /token ID, smart contracts and wallets/ and the other is the image you see in the market. If the image that motivates the purchase disappears because it is programmed in the smart contracts, what does the buyer of the NFT keep? just with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes just the ownership of that tokenID.